# Can't add footer to some pdf in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using itextsharp. I can add footer to some pdf but some I can't. Here's my code:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(PPTpath);
Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
    using (stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
    {
        //stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
        {
            //ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetUnderContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase("Generated ECAB", blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase("Generated ECAB", blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
        }
    }
    bytes = stream.ToArray();
    stamper.Close();
}
File.WriteAllBytes(PPTpath, bytes);
```

Here's the link of pdf I tried to add footer https://dl.ubnt.com/datasheets/airfiber/airFiber_DS.pdf. Can someone explain why I can't add footer to this pdf file. Thank you

Comment: I'll look in detail later but one obvious probable cause is that you use fixed coordinates in `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned`. Thus, you expect a fixed coordinate system. PDFs, on the other hand, can have different coordinate systems on each page, merely often the origin is in the lower left.

Comment: @mkl ok sir how can i have dynamic coordinate?

Comment: I ran your code as is (merely writing the result to a different file) and it worked out of the box, the footer was added! Do you probably merely not have the permissions to overwrite that file? Which iTextSharp version do you use? I obviously use the most current 5.5.x: 5.5.13.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in a comment, the code in question works fine with the shared PDF, the only differences being that I use a different file for the result and that I declare the variable `stamper`. Thus, probably the OP is not allowed to overwrite the file in question.

That being said, there indeed is an issue in the code which may or may not sometimes cause problems:

#### Assumed coordinate system

The OP uses fixed coordinates when drawing the footer:

```
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
    new Phrase("Generated ECAB", blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
```

This works well as long the page has a width like LETTER or A4 but for smaller paper formats the string might be cut off.

Furthermore these coordinates assume that the origin of the coordinate system is in the lower left corner of the visible page. While this is often the case, it does not need to be. Each page may define its own visible window of the underlying contents canvas.

Concerning both potential problems you can counteract by calculating the coordinates based on the page crop box values:

```
Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetCropBox(i);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
    new Phrase("Generated ECAB", blackFont), cropBox.GetRight(44f), cropBox.GetBottom(15f), 0);
```

This puts the anchor point of the text 44 units left of the right paper border and 15 units above the bottom border.

Furthermore, there is a minor weirdness:

#### Closing the stamper after the using block

The OP defines the `stamper` outside the `using` and closes it thereafter.

First of all, already at the end of the `using` block the `stamper` automatically is closed, so closing it again thereafter is at best a no-operation. Thus, the OP should remove that `Close` call.

Additionally, it is unclear where the OP declared that `stamper` variable. If he e.g. defined it as a class member, he might run into issues if that class is used from multiple threads; as the `stamper` is created at the start of the `using` and disposed at the end of the `using` block, I would recommend declaring it in the `using`, i.e.:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
    {
        //stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
        {
            Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetCropBox(i);
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                new Phrase("Generated ECAB", blackFont), cropBox.GetRight(44f), cropBox.GetBottom(15f), 0);
        }
    }
    bytes = stream.ToArray();
}
```